# how to go back using github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, git-bash

I'm doing ruby on rails, and I messed up I want to go back to the previous step I saved on github. problem is I don't know how to go back, do I delete my files and paste the one I saved on github? is there an easier way I can do it on gitbash?

Comment: It would appear your best bet at this point is to [learn git with GitHub](http://try.github.com).

Comment: git is pretty much designed for being able to go through your code history.  there is a much more elegant and simple way than deleting files and pasting them in.   Check out this s.o. question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit

Answer (score 0):

If the previous step if the one you pushed to GitHub (meaning the same sha1 that you would see for `origin/master` when doing a `git branch -avvv`), all you need is:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

You current branch (I assume master) is reset to `origin/master`, and you can resume your work from the same point as the last one you pushed to GitHub.